# How to make a Poligon with a width of the 50% of the screen

Tags: android, opengl-es

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How i can forze the size of a square to their texture size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929009/how-i-can-forze-the-size-of-a-square-to-their-texture-size)
>   [How i can make that a polygon fill the 80% of the width of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951216/how-i-can-make-that-a-polygon-fill-the-80-of-the-width-of-the-screen)

Having a square (polygon), i want that it fills the 80% of the width of the screen

It is possible to do it?

Comment: Please don't ask identical, or *almost* identical questions twice.

Comment: no, they are not almost identical, completly different problems and questions. Here i am not talking about resizing into a texture size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your square should extend from -0.8f to 0.8f. Thus it will fill 1.6/2 = 80% of the display. Use:

```
private float vertices[] = 
{ 
    -0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,     //Bottom Left
    0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,      //Bottom Right
    -0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f,      //Top Left
    0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f        //Top Right
};
```

Comment: it doesn't work, are you sure about it? The image get's smaller and a little moved

Comment: I didn't know you wanted it centered, I updated my answer

Comment: how have to be positioned the square on the Z axis to fill 80% of the screen with these vertices? Now i have the square positioned at z=-5.0, and the square is too small, is not the 80% of the screen

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about filling this rectangle you're talking about, but if you want the position at 80% of the screen in width (x position) you can do that with this:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
float widthEightyPercent = Math.round(display.getWidth() * 0.8);
```

Comment: i dont want to position at 80% of the screen, i want to position on the center, but with a width of the 80% of the total width of the screen